# iOS / iPhone SDK: Is there an event for when network is lost / back?

Tags: ios, events, networking, sdk

I would like to do some treatment when i loose connection, and when connection is back.
Are there any events to handle it ?

Thanks by advance,

E.

Comment: You could take help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501864/reachability-network-change-event-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

You should use good practices used in [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).
They use [Reachability](http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24) which is as they say a drop in replacement of the class develop by [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)
I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

One standard approach is to use **Reachability** to test network availability. It can be downloaded [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). You only need Reachability.h and Reachability.m in your project.

My personal preference is to do the following -

1 Add the Reachability files

2 Create BOOL properties for each network test you wish to remember/expose in your project - I have a test for google and a test for google maps below.

3 In your appDidFinishLoading method call [self assertainNetworkReachability].

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Reachability

-(void)assertainNetworkReachability {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundReachabilityTests)  withObject:nil];
}

-(void)backgroundReachabilityTests {

    self.isInternetReachable = [self internetReachable];
    self.isMapsReachable = [self mapsReachable];

    self.connectivityTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self     selector:@selector(backgroundReachabilityTests) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(BOOL)hostReachable:(NSString*)host {
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:host];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        [self throwNetworkDiagnosisAlert];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)internetReachable {
    return [self hostReachable:@"www.google.co.uk"];
}

-(BOOL)mapsReachable {
    return [self hostReachable:@"maps.google.com"];
}

-(BOOL)isInternetGoodYetMapsUnreachable {
    return (self.isInternetReachable && !self.isMapsReachable);
}

-(void)throwNetworkDiagnosisAlert {
    NSString* title = @"Connectivity Problem";
    NSString* message = @"You are not connected to the internet.";

    if (self.isInternetGoodYetMapsUnreachable) {
        message = @"Unable to connect to the Google Maps server.";
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```